# Write a confirmation column (CSV) for each loop entry iMacros

Tags: csv, input, scripting, imacros

I am using an iMacros script to to pull data from a csv (col1) and run some steps based on the info in col1.

Because I am running the script hundreds of times once (loop) and sometimes the script brakes, i sometimes don't know where the loop stopped.

I want to put a command at script's end to write "1" or "x" in col2 of the corresponding line (loop number). In this way, even if I don't know at which loop entry the script broke, if I open the CSV, i'll have the 2nd column completed with "1" or "x" for each of the succesfuly finished loop.

for taking the input from the csv i use:

```
SET !DATASOURCE worksheet1.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
...
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:keywrd ATTR=ID:keyword CONTENT={{!COL1}}
```

and that works perfectly but i just want to know how can i write to col2 so i have a confirmation once the script loop is finished

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `SAVEAS` Command can only append New Lines to an existing File, so you won't be able to add a 2nd Column to your existing "worksheet1.csv" File, but you can  save what you want to a 2nd (separate) File... :idea:

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can post my Comment as an Answer...:

The `SAVEAS` Command can only append New Lines to an existing File, so you won't be able to add a 2nd Column to your existing "worksheet1.csv" File, but you can save what you want to a 2nd (separate) File... :idea:

For example:

```scala
SET !DATASOURCE worksheet1.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

' ... 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:keywrd ATTR=ID:keyword CONTENT={{!COL1}}

SET !EXTRACT {{!LOOP}}[EXTRACT]{{!COL1}}[EXTRACT]{{!NOW:yyyy-mm-dd_hh:nn}}[EXTRACT]x
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=Worksheet1.log
```

(The '.log' File will be saved in your Default `\Downloads\` Folder, you can "adjust" the `FOLDER` and/or `FILE` Params if you "prefer" to have the File saved "next to" the "original" '.csv' DataSource, in the same `\DataSource\` Folder...)

Comment: For Info, I referred/linked to this Solution of mine in some similar Thread on the iMacros Forum: - "Minimal way to read and update data with iMacros" ( https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=31814&p=88332&sid=d2a91d6080e68ec9fe5e8b43cf0a6b98#p88332 ) + Quote of the whole Thread in case this one "disappears" one day...